# What is the ​ "this effect" ​ that doesn't remove White Ward?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[White Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWhite%20Ward%5d) is a white aura whose Oracle text is:

> Enchant creature
>
> Enchanted creature has protection from white. This effect doesn't remove white ward.

Is ​"this effect" the "protection from white" ​that the enchanted creature has or the "Enchanted creature has protection from white." that White Ward has?

This should matter if [some other ability gives that creature protection from white](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+%5B%22gains%20protection%20from%20white%22%5D).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It refers just to the protection granted by White Ward, not protection granted by other effects.

The easiest way to see this is just to look at another similar card, [Spectra Ward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectra%20Ward%5d):

> Enchanted creature gets +2/+2 and has protection from all colors. This effect doesn't remove Auras.

That's the same language as White Ward, and it has a ruling in Gatherer:

> The protection granted by Spectra Ward won’t cause any Aura to be put into its owner’s graveyard, including Spectra Ward itself. However, if the enchanted creature gains protection from white in another way, Spectra Ward will be put into its owner’s graveyard as a state-based action.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when Magic uses the word "this", it refers to a specific instance, not a class of objects. So, "this creature" refers to a specific creature, not any creature with the same name. Similarly, "this effect" on White Ward refers to the specific instance of "Protection from White" that it grants to the creature. Even if it got another instance of Protection from White somehow, it would not come with the same caveat.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this, I assume you believe that with White Ward being White that the effect would grant it protection from the spell itself. This would render the card completely useless so to combat this the card also has an exception from the effect for the Enchantment itself.

The effect does not "effect" the card that grants the effect, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think what the question is asking is actually the other way around: he understands that White Ward does not remove himself. What he's asking is whether any *other* instances of "Protection from White" will have the same modifier to not remove White Ward.

Comment: Yeah... I think I get from the last sentence however it is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "Enchanted creature has protection from white" ​is an ability, not an effect. This ability creates a continuous effect that grants the enchanted creature protection from white. This is the effect to which the card refers.

...Except it's not. That would be the case is White Ward was written correctly. The problem is that this effect isn't the one that would cause the White Ward to be removed. It's actually the effect created by the granted "Protection from White" ability that would cause the White Ward to be removed. So obviously, that's the effect to which the card actually refers.

Without neutering the Protection from White it grants, White Ward would protect the creature from being enchanted by White Ward, sending White Ward to the graveyard.

Of course, it only neuters the Protection from White it grants. If the creature has any other instance of Protection from White, those will still apply.